# flutter video_player(or chewie) enter full screen on landscape mode like youtube

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need a video player that enters full screen when the device is rotated to landscape mode and back. Just like how the video player in apps like YouTube and Udemy. I am using chewie and there is an open issue about it in
https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/issues/15
From that, I found this solution
https://gist.github.com/ihrankouski/0a353a8de649b648b3ceff0d8e97f1d7
which has a problem that it won't come back to the normal position on portrait mode.

also, there is a file in the chewie example
https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/blob/master/example/lib/auto_rotate.dart
that does this(maybe. I don't know what the code is for) but is not working when I tried. Does this have any problem? If yes then what is the problem?

Is there another library that has this functionality,  If yes how can this be done with that library.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this to work for my purposes with the help of Youtuber Johannes Milke's Video [video link](https://youtu.be/x0ZNQ0YXyfE?t=1032). Also posted on chewie's github [here](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/chewie/issues/431). His approach works like this:

First, you add the package `native_device_orientation` to your dependencies. Then, in the initstate where you initialize the `ChewieController` you listen for orientation changes requested by the user, detected by the smartphone's sensor (hence, the `useSensor: true` flag is vital here).
If now the sensor detects, that the user wants to be in portrait mode, but the Chewie player is currently in fullscreen mode, you command the widgets to return to `SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);`, so to the currently sensed phone orientation.
It is set to values - so all possible orientations - as not to force the phone in the portrait orientation, which could then block your app going into landscape mode on any other page.
Also you call `_chewieController.exitFullScreen();`, so that Chewie knows what's going on.

Then I also cover the opposite case, so the phone wanting to be in portrait, but the chewieController being in fullscreen. This is the code:

```
 NativeDeviceOrientationCommunicator()
            .onOrientationChanged(useSensor: true)
            .listen((event) {
          final bool isPortrait = (event == NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp ||
              event == NativeDeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
          final bool isLandscape =
              (event == NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft ||
                  event == NativeDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight);
    
          if (isPortrait && _chewieController.isFullScreen) {
        _chewieController.exitFullScreen();
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
          } else if (isLandscape && !_chewieController.isFullScreen) {
        _chewieController.enterFullScreen();
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);  
          }
        });
```

Also, I added this to my ChewieController:

```
deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [
          DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
          DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
        ]
```

Last but not least I added a `WillPopScope` above the Chewie widget, that guarantees, that my app will not get stuck in any rotation, even when the user hits the "back" button on android. Like so:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
        return true;
      },
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: aspectRatio,
        child: Chewie(
          controller: _chewieController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this works just fine for me so far!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding fullscreen you can added it as a parameter to your ChewieController

```
_chewieController = ChewieController(
  _videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
  fullScreenByDefault: true);
```

Regarding Orientation you can set that in the initiState()

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializePlayer();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: and remember on dispose to set the screen back to vertical

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]); 
     _controller.dispose();
  }